# Chemical accuracy and room temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, density-functional-theory

Chemical accuracy is $\pu{2E-2 eV}$ but room temperature $\pu{20 ^\circ C}$ is $\pu{2.5E-2 eV}$, so why is it not necessary to take into account thermal effects in DFT? I understood (maybe wrongly) that chemical accuracy is the precision we want on electronic energies for one atom or one molecule.

Comment: [$\mathrm{k_B T}$ at room temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KT_(energy)) is about $\mathrm{25\ meV}$.

Comment: Right, sorry ! still it's the same order of magnitude than chemical accuracy... so why it's not necessary to take into account thermal effects in DFT ?

Comment: About precission and accuracy, see [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/139618/35806)

Comment: DFT can be used to describe electronic structure (and more). It is used nowadays with different functionals, which I like to call density functional approximations (DFA). Most of them have errors beyond chemical accuracy. And there are further approximations, which could handle  thermal effects. I'm not quite sure whether I understand the question right, maybe it would be helpful if you could add some more context. In any case: Welcome to Chemistry.se!

Comment: Thanks ! It's because I read that some DFT approximations reach chemical accuracy, but I don't understand how it's possible since they don't take into account thermal effects while temperature energy is close to this precision. For instance let us think of computing the ionisation energy of an atom with between 10 and 20 electrons.

Comment: What is *chemical accuracy*, and why is it 20meV?